# Time resets after reboot

Tags: 11.04, time

My Time zone is GMT and the time is set to 5 hours before this every time I reboot (American time?)

Ubuntu 11.04 64b
Dual boot with Win7
ASUS M4A78LT-M

Comment: Does this happen on Ubuntu 10.10 as well?

Comment: I used to have very similar problem when I used to double-boot. I guess the point is that windows sets BIOS's clock to UTC, while ubuntu prefers the local time (or something like that). However, I've never managed to fix it - but anyway I can confirm this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure it has the correct location in System->Administration->Time and Date. All thought you may have selected UK in location options in the installer, you have to set clock location from America to Britain

Answer (score 1):

when you installed ubuntu you set it to UTC time. seriously, ive made the mistake. always 7 hrs difference between computer time and bios time. its in ubuntu time and date settings.

Answer (score 0):

Could your BIOS be wrong, Has your computer shown "CMOS Bad" error? It may be time to replace your battery or change your settings!

Comment: Wouldn't it set the year to 2007 or something rather than 5 hours less than the current time?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this on Acer eee notebook 2 weeks ago
ive put wubi netbook ubuntu version for one friend and its time was always reseting to gmt +1 but needed is gmt +2
location was set but still maybe windows 7 reseting somehow.